# Find the limit $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}k\int_{[1-\frac{1}{k}, 1]}f(x) \text{d}x$ when $\text{spt}(f)\subset [0, 2]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have the following problem. Find the limit $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}k\int_{[1-\frac{1}{k}, 1]}f(x) \text{d}x$$ if it exists, when $f$ is continuous and has compact support in $[0, 2]$. I tried dominated convergence but got stuck because the function $kf(x)$ tends to infinity and the interval tends to single point $\{1\}$ and thus the integral is zero. But that integral looks like integrating w.r.t. Dirac delta function so I guess the answer should be $f(1)$. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that:
$$k\int_{[1-\frac{1}{k},1]}f(1)= f(1)$$
Now, can use the continuity of $f(x)$ at $1$?

Comment: i don't really understand this hint, how can I use the continuity of $f$?

Comment: Choose $\delta>0$ such that $f(1)-\epsilon <f(x)< f(1)+\epsilon$  whenever $1-\delta<x<1+\delta$. Now choose k large enough so that $[1-\frac{1}{k},1]$ is contained in $[1-\delta,1]$.
Then by the monotonicity of the integral, you have:
$k\int_{[1-\frac{1}{k}]} \left[f(1)-\epsilon \right] < k \int_{[1-\frac{1}{k}]}f(x)<  k\int_{[1-\frac{1}{k}]} \left[f(1)+\epsilon \right] $

Comment: Yes, now I got it, thank you very much. By the way, does the claim then follow if $f$ is merely bounded or intergrable?

Comment: It's not true if $f$ is not continuous, Consider $f(x)=1$ if $x \in \mathbb{R} - \left\{1\right\}$ and $f(1)=0$, then $\lim k \int _{[1-\frac{1}{k},1]} f(x) = 1$

Comment: maybe in your example $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$?

Comment: You're correct, I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

If  $f(x)$ is continuous in $\subset [0, 2]$, it exist some $F(x)=\int f(x) \text{d}x$, continuous an derivable in the same region.
So by Barrow we have

$$I=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}k\int_{[1-\frac{1}{k}, 1]}f(x) \text{d}x=
=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}k [F(1)-F(1-\frac{1}{k})]$$

Now as $F(x)$ is derivable with continuity at $x=1$, we can expand it in some neighbourhood  by Taylor
$$F(1-\frac{1}{k})=F(1)-\frac{1}{k}F'(1)+O(x^2)=F(1)-\frac{1}{k}f(1)+O(\frac{1}{k^2})$$

So by substituing

$$I=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}k [F(1)-F(1)+\frac{1}{k}f(1)-O(\frac{1}{k^2})]
=f(1)-\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}k O(\frac{1}{k^2})=f(1)$$

Comment: interesting approach, thank you for this answer